# SQL Managment inicia y antes del login se cierra

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, ssms

La consulta es la siguiente:
**¿Por qué el SQL inicia y antes de mostrarme el login se cierra solo?**

Contexto.
Instale Sql Server - Sql Managmente Studio 2018.
Funcionaba perfecto, estuve trabajando hasta hace unos días.
Me conecte a la base de datos del trabajo con el SQL desde mi maquina y trabaje normalmente, al día siguiente corro el SQL y antes de mostrarme el login se cierra solo, a veces se queda tildado cargando y como no puede continuar se cierra.
Esto me sucedió en la cuenta secundaria que tengo (administrador).
Para probar ingrese a mi cuenta primaria y el SQL Managmente funcionaba lo mas bien con localhost. Inicie con la base de datos del trabajo y paso lo mismo.

Alguien tiene una idea de que puede ser, o como editar las credenciales sin abrir el managmente o como indicar que no se conecte al iniciar el sql.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo error, ingreso al sql y luego se sale solo sin decir nada de error, solo se sale, entro ah sql profiler y se conecta normal, solo en sql se sale, creo que el problema es la app, o no se, ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude "resolver".
Ingrese a la carpeta donde apunta el acceso directo del sql managment.
Luego ingrese a SQL Profiler. al intentar conectarse no pudo y tiro un mensaje de error.
Luego intente otra vez y me aparecio el login con las credenciales de mi trabajo.
Inicie como local host y ya tengo la misma base que tenia antes.

Ya esta funcionando SQL en mi maquina pero en realidad nunca dejo de funcinar al parecer.
No se porque con las credenciales de mi trabajo pasa eso.
Debe ser algo de la red o algo asi creo.
Si alguien tiene una idea puedo buscar.

Saludos.